# How to take backup of Tableau Server Repository(PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, tableau-api

we are using **2018.3 version of Tableau Server**. The server stats like user login, and other stats are getting logged into PostgreSQL DB. and the same being cleared regularly after 1 week.

Is there any API available in Tableau to connect the DB and take backup of data somewhere like HDFS or any place in Linux server.

Kindly let me know if there are any other way other than API as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable access to the underlying PostgreSQL repository database with the tsm command. Here is a link to the documentation for your (older) version of Tableau

https://help.tableau.com/v2018.3/server/en-us/cli_data-access.htm#repository-access-enable

It would be good security practice to limit access to only the machines (whitelisted) that need it, create or use an existing read-only account to access the repository, and ideally to disable access when your admin programs are complete (i.e.. enable access, do your query, disable access)

This way you can have any SQL client code you wish query the repository, create a mirror, create reports, run auditing procedures - whatever you like.

Personally, before writing significant custom code, I’d first see if the info you want is already available another way, in one of the built in admin views, via the REST API, or using the public domain LogShark or TabMon systems or with the Addon (for more recent versions of Tableau) the Server Management Add-on, or possibly the new Data Catalog.

I know at least one server admin who somehow clones the whole Postgres repository database periodically so he can analyze stats offline. Not sure what approach he uses to clone. So you have several options.